Remove Apollo Graphql Subgraph features for `_service` and `_entities`
Using this question as an example, how do we remove Apollo Graphql Subgraph features for _service and _entities fields?
We are using Java Spring Boot and Netflix RDS also.
This helped to remove graphl introspection.
Disable GraphQL Introspection in graphql-java-tools
